# Loading chartjs-plugin-zoom provokes error

Tags: chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have an application that uses chart.js which works.

I wanted the ability to zoom-in on areas and decided to do this with chartjs-plugin-zoom. However when I load the scripts, I get an error (and zooming doesn't work).

It never executes any of my code - it's all going wrong in the  tags loading the files:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Charts</title>
        <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.3.3/dist/chart.js"
                crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@2.0.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello, World!
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try this (Firefox, Chrome), it throws TypeError: e.Chart is undefined when loading the chartjs-plugin-zoom module.

It appears that "global.Chart" isn't defined when executing the fourth line of code - the factory(...) call.

```
(global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' ? globalThis : global || self, global.ChartZoom = factory(global.Chart, global.Hammer, global.Chart.helpers));
```

I have tried other CDN repositories, and hosting the downloaded files locally. The result is the same.

What have I missed?